# nullpointer exception for logger

Tags: logging, junit4, cobertura, spring-test

the below code is not working

```
@BeforeClass    
public static void setUp() {
            service=new BusManager();
            logger = mock(Logger.class);
            when(logger.isDebugEnabled()).thenReturn(true);
            doAnswer(new MakePersistentCallback()).when(logger).debug(argStr.capture());
            mockStatic(Logger.class);
            when(Logger.getLogger(argClass.capture())).thenReturn(logger);
            entityMngr = mock(IEntityMgr.class);

            applicationBusManager = mock(ApplicationBusManager.class);
            antityManagerFactory = mock(EntityManagerFactory.class);
            applicationEntityMgr=mock(ApplicationEntityMgr.class);
            userApplicationEntityMgr=mock(UserApplicationEntityMgr.class);
            disBusManager=mock(DisBusManager.class);



            ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service,"entityManagerFactory",entityManagerFactory);
            ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service,"applicationBusManager",applicationBusManager); 
            ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service,"disBusManager",disBusManager); 



            when(entityManagerFactory.getEntityManager("applicationEntityMgr")).thenReturn(applicationEntityMgr);

            when(entityManagerFactory.getEntityManager("applicationEntityMgr")).thenReturn(applicationEntityMgr);


        }
```

it is showing the following error.my aim is to give the cobertura report also along with junits.i have to cover logger also...so i put logger code prior to intialization of the testing class..

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.isDebugEnabled(Log4JLogger.java:299)
        at org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.setField(ReflectionTestUtils.java:109)
        at org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.setField(ReflectionTestUtils.java:81)
        at
```

withour logger mock the code is working fine..but i need to work logger also..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while debug the reflectionutils is the line where it is creating problem.So i did use the setter methods of the testing class to inject these objects and run it is working fine..